# Texmaker - easy approach to edit large paragraphs (jump to line) - inverse search

Tags: texmaker, forward-inverse-search

Editor: TexMaker

I have been searching for a while, but couldn't find a practical solution. I am writing an article, and the problem is when I need to edit. When I find a mistake in the pdf, I use the "jump to line, syncTex" command. It used to work fine, but now that I am having big paragraphs; it either go to the beginning or the end of the paragraph and I have to search  again for the line that contains the mistake! It is a real headache, and I know there must be an easy solution for this, such as a "go-to-word" tool, I have tried some ideas like adding empty equation but it doesn't work!. I am willing to change the editor if others provide this functionality.

Any suggestions are very appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the reasons I always break my paragraphs into multiple lines in the source. The other is for revision with version control systems (Subversion, Mercurial, Git, etc.).