# Is there a tool that converts "normally written" TeX source to one with a newline at the end of every sentence?

Tags: tools

In many of the questions asked here, people recommend the use of control versioning for the write-up LaTeX documents, especially for documents that are large, such as theses.

The issue with doing that is that in order for the traditional control versioning `diff` to be of any use, sentences must be broken into lines. Otherwise, `diff` doesn't really provide any insight as to what changed in the document and things get messy really fast.

The plan is for all my new documents to follow the "each-sentence-in-a-new-line" format. But I would like to start using control versioning for some of my existing (and large) documents.

I was wondering whether there's a tool that takes a `.tex` file as input and spits out a new `.tex` file in which the sentences are separated by a newline character. I am mainly interested in a UNIX tool, but the more portable, the better.

**Note:** The problem is not as simple as inserting a newline after every period unfortunately. For example, when the tool finds "e.g." in the text, it needs to be smart enough to avoid inserting a newline there. Or, more of an annoyance instead of a big issue, since the last character in a paragraph is very likely to be a period, it needs to avoid inserting an extra newline there. Maybe a tool that utilises the LaTeX internals to identify when a sentence has actually ended?

Comment: I suppose Emacs can do that.

Comment: @giordano I assume it does that with regular expressions? I'd be willing to use Emacas just for the sake of converting my source. Then back to Sublime Text it is. `:-)` Can you show an example of that please?

Comment: Since the original conversion happens just once, consider emacs query-replace, turning periods followed by blanks to periods followed by carriage returns. That might handle enough of the problem to make diff useful.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes, that is simple enough. I can do that myself. But I was just wondering whether there's a more elegant solution. There would be too many things that require fixing otherwise.

Comment: Having separated sentences also helps sync with the document viewer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121615/texmaker-easy-approach-to-edit-large-paragraphs-jump-to-line-inverse-searc

Comment: @sudosensei possible idea: you can try to bind the space key to a lambda that inserts a new line char if the previous char is a period, a space char otherwise. This doesn't convert the text but allows you to separate the sentences as you write.

Comment: Found this on StackOverflow: [convert paragraph into sentence using Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15737359/943299).

Comment: A regular expression would look something like this: `/([.,;:!?"”–—])\w+([:uppercase:])/$1 \n$2/`, i.e. look for punctuation followed by at least one whitespace (`\w` or `[ \t]`) followed by an uppercase letter (`[A-Z]` would work for English), and replace the whitespace by a space followed by a single newline, keep the rest as is. Note that some RX flavors use `\1` instead of `$1`.

Comment: Note that \w is a 'word' character in sed. Something like sed '/\\begin{document}/,/\\end{document}/s/^\([^%]*\. \)\([A-Z]\)/\1 %\n\2/g' should catch many instances. Note that this is largely untested since you don't provide a MWE to test with. It certainly will not catch sentences beginning with a quotation mark, for example, and will only work reliably for English. ([:uppercase:] as suggested above would remove the latter limitation.) It will also miss cases where the full stop is within a command or where the next sentence starts with a command. It will avoid splitting comments, though.

Comment: I wasn't aware there was already an answer to this question (despite the fact that the question was different). Apologies. Thanks for the insightful comments, everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Convert an old document

Here is my take in Emacs Lisp (Emacs runs on [several operating systems](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/#Platforms), so I think it's really portable).  It isn't bullet-proof but can be improved:

```lisp
(defun mg-split-paragraphs-into-sentences ()
  "Split paragraphs into sentences the current buffer.
Newlines within a sentence are removed."
  (interactive)
  (let ((sentence-end-double-space nil))
    ;; Go to beginning of the buffer.
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (null (eobp))
      ;; Move to the end of the next sentence.
      (forward-sentence)
      ;; Skip the white spaces.
      (skip-chars-forward " \t")
      ;; Delete all new lines in the current sentence.
      (save-excursion
    (save-match-data
      (while (re-search-backward
          "\\(\n\\|\r\\)"
          (save-excursion (backward-sentence) (point))
          t)
        (replace-match "" nil nil))))
      ;; Insert a new line if needed.
      (if (null (eq (following-char) ?\n))
      (LaTeX-newline)))))
```

Emacs assumes by default [double sentence spacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_spacing) (which is useful to distinguish between the end of a sentence and of an abbreviation), but can be told to use single sentence spacing by setting `sentence-end-double-space` to `nil`.  If your documents use double sentence spacing change the

```lisp
(sentence-end-double-space nil)
```

into

```lisp
(sentence-end-double-space t)
```

The functions uses `LaTeX-newline` which is a LaTeX comments aware functions to insert newlines provided by AUCTeX.  If you don't use AUCTeX replace

```lisp
(LaTeX-newline)
```

with

```lisp
(newline)
```

but `newline` isn't LaTeX comments aware.  You can run the function with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `mg-split-paragraphs-into-sentences` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

### Automatically insert a newline after a sentence while writing new documents

As I suggested in the comments, for new documents one can bind the space key to a function which check whether the sentence is ended.

```lisp
(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(progn
     (define-key LaTeX-mode-map " "
       (lambda ()
     (interactive)
     (if
         (save-match-data
           (save-excursion
         (re-search-backward (concat (sentence-end) "\\=")
                     (save-excursion (beginning-of-line)) t)))
         (LaTeX-newline)
       (insert " "))))))
```

If one needs to insert a space after a period can use <kbd>C-q SPC</kbd>.

Comment: This looks great. I might actually have to give Emacs a shot. `:-)` I'll mark this answer as accepted since it is a duplicate question. Thanks for the help.